# STM32 sending value via UART to serial port

Tags: c, serial-port, stm32, uart

I'm using potentiometer to control servo motor. I want to send the servo angle value to serial port via UART. First, i was getting unknown characters. Now, it prints "Servo: 0 " everytime but i'm changing the value.

```html
uint32_t potadc;
uint32_t servopot;
char str[32];

int size_len = sprintf (str, "Servo : %lu\n", servopot, 0xFFFF);


while {
servopot = potadc/6;

HAL_UART_Transmit (&huart2, (uint8_t *)str, size_len, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
          HAL_Delay(1000);
        
        }
```

Comment: This code is weird. You're continuously (forever) sending the exact same string, which happens to contain `"Servo: xxx"`, where `xxx` is the value of an (uninitialized!!!) local variable. While this is perfectly legal to do so, I don't quite understand what you're hoping to achieve by that.

Comment: Move the *sprintf* statement into the *while* loop. Otherwise the same text line initially created will always be sent to the serial connection

Comment: How and where exactly are you setting the variable `potadc`? Is it a local variable in a function, or a global variable which you are setting in some other thread?

Comment: `potentiometer`, `servo motor`, `servo angle` - all these "things" seem either unrelated to the question, or the relevant information about them is missing. Even if you do move that `sprintf` line into the `while` loop, it's not gonna change the fact that you will continue to get the same printout. You need to elaborate about the `potadc` variable, as I mentioned in the comment above. Some vital information is missing here. More generally, unless this code is a part of a multi-threaded program, it seems pretty useless.

Comment: Firstly, I'm not experienced at coding. Pretty newbie, that's why you find my code weird. Secondly, i didn't share all the codes because there are too much setup codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sprintf` has to be **inside** the loop otherwise it will be executed only once before entering the loop/.

```
int size_len;

while(1) {
    servopot = potadc/6;
    size_len = sprintf (str, "Servo : %u\n", servopot);
    HAL_UART_Transmit (&huart2, (uint8_t *)str, size_len, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
    HAL_Delay(1000);        
}
```

Comment: @user253751 don't you know?

Comment: I do know, but to make this a good answer, you should explain it.

Comment: It's actually rather difficult to make a good answer for a low-quality question. The context for `potadc` is missing from that question, and as it stands (both in the question and in this answer), it is still going to yield the exact same printout (of some garbage value) over and over.

Comment: potadc is the value of the potentiometer from ADC, which taken 0-1023 value in debug screen. Servo has 0-170 degree angle. I make the calculation, potadc/6 to get the real angle of the servo "servopot".

Answer (score 0):

I moved the

```html
int size_len = sprintf (str, "Servo : %lu\n", servopot, 0xFFFF);
```

code to the loop, it worked. Thanks everyone who tried to answer.